# Select pandas Series elements based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, series

Given a dataframe, I know I can select rows by condition using below syntax:

`df[df['colname'] == 'Target Value']`

But what about a Series? Series does not have a column (axis 1) name, right?

My scenario is I have created a Series by through the nunique() function:

`sr = df.nunique()`

And I want to list out the index names of those rows with value 1.

Having failed to find a clear answer on the Net, I resorted to below solution:

```
for (colname, coldata) in sr.iteritems(): 
   if coldata == 1: 
      print(colname)
```

Question: what is a better way to get my answer (i.e list out index names of Series (or column names of the original Dataframe) which has just a single value?)

The ultimate objective was to find which columns in a DF has one and only one unique value. Since I did not know how to do that direct from a DF, I first used nunique() and that gave me a Series. Thus i needed to process the Series with a "== 1" (i.e one and only one)

I hope my question isnt silly.

Comment: what a shame user1740577 elected to delete his/her answer. all 3 answers inherently led to the result I needed, just that one gives a list, another an index and the other a Series

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is unclear what you want. Whether you want to work on the dataframe or on the Series ?

### Case 1: Working on DataFrame

In case you want to work on the dataframe to to list out the index names **of those rows with value 1**, you can try:

```
df.index[df[df==1].any(axis=1)].tolist()
```

**Demo**

```
data = {'Col1': [0, 1, 2, 2, 0], 'Col2': [0, 2, 2, 1, 2], 'Col3': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     0     0     0
1     1     2     0
2     2     2     0
3     2     1     0
4     0     2     1
```

Then, run the code, it gives:

```
[1, 3, 4]
```

---

### Case 2: Working on Series

If you want to extract the index of a Series with value 1, you can extract it into a list, as follows:

```
sr.loc[sr == 1].index.tolist()
```

or use:

```
sr.index[sr == 1].tolist()
```

Comment: Thanx SeaBean gshpychka user1740577
All good (eventually) and different answers (approaches), but arising from "Accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution", SeaBean gets the nod (I'm torn - can I accept more than one? - cos all three answers had merits and demerits, all three in one way or other 'solved' my problem but SeaBean's Case 2 was arguably the nicest cos it came out in a more readable list format)
@gshpychka was the most succinct though, and includes a teaching element

Comment: My summary comment: Case 2 here is the most helpful answer (Case 1 not for my scenario cos "1" can only be referenced after going thru the nunique() func)

Answer (score 3):

It would work the same way, due to the fact that pandas overloads the `==` operator:

`selected_series = series[series == my_value]`

Comment: thanx gshpychka, altho i m unable to upvote your answer cos insufficient rep. i'll come back to upvote when i hv enough (why did u delete your comment on the other answer?)

Comment: The other answer was removed by moderators due to the poster's behavior.